# Check all items in loop query and continue only if all match the desired result

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
faces_all = list(range(1,25)) # Create list numbered 1-24
for x in itertools.combinations((faces_all),3): # check combinations in numbers 2-23
     if faces_all[0] + sum(x) == 50: # if 1 + combination = 50 continue
        for pair in itertools.combinations([faces_all[0],x],2): # HELP
          if pair != 25:
```

What I want to be able to do is ONLY continue if every combination of `faces_all[0]` and `x` (should be 4 numbers,  6 combinations of 2 numbers) is NOT equal to 25.

If even one combination of 2 numbers equals 25, the next combination for `x` should be iterated...

I'm a Python novice and my only previous experience is unstructured BASIC.

Comment: Can you reword "(should be 4 numbers, 6 combinations of 2 numbers)" I don't understand that sentence.\

Comment: Basically, as noted in the answer below, it should be creating a new list of 4 numbers, where there are only 6 possible pairs - 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 and 3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `[faces_all[0],x]` creates a list of two elements. The first element is `faces_all[0]` (in this case always 1) and the second element is `x`, which is a tuple of 3 numbers itself. What you want in this case is a list of 4 numbers. You can create it like this: `[faces_all[0], x[0], x[1], x[2]]`.

Tip: if you add `print(repr(pair))` before the last if-statement you can see the results of the second call to `itertools.combinations()`.

Before:

```
(1, (2, 23, 24))
(1, (3, 22, 24))
(1, (4, 21, 24))
...
```

After:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 23)
(1, 24)
(2, 23)
(2, 24)
(23, 24)
(1, 3)
(1, 22)
(1, 24)
(3, 22)
(3, 24)
(22, 24)
(1, 4)
(1, 21)
(1, 24)
(4, 21)
(4, 24)
(21, 24)
...
```

**UPDATE**

Now, once you have the correct number pairs, you could check if the sum of the numbers is 25 and break the for-loop if this is the case. (Note that `itertools.combinations()` returns a generator, meaning that the next pairs are not 'calculated' if you break from the loop.)

The complete code could be something like this. Note the `for-else` statement, which does not exist in most languages, and is convenient in this case. The else statement is reached when the for-loop is completed 'normally' (i.e. without break).

```
import itertools

faces_all = list(range(1, 25))  # Create list numbered 1-24
for x in itertools.combinations((faces_all), 3):  # check combinations in numbers 2-23
     if faces_all[0] + sum(x) == 50:  # if 1 + combination = 50 continue
        four_numbers = (faces_all[0], x[0], x[1], x[2])
        for pair in itertools.combinations(four_numbers, 2):
            if sum(pair) == 25:
                break
        else:
            print(repr(four_numbers))
```

The output of above code is:

```
(1, 4, 22, 23)
(1, 5, 21, 23)
(1, 6, 20, 23)
(1, 6, 21, 22)
(1, 7, 19, 23)
(1, 7, 20, 22)
(1, 8, 18, 23)
(1, 8, 19, 22)
(1, 8, 20, 21)
(1, 9, 17, 23)
(1, 9, 18, 22)
(1, 9, 19, 21)
(1, 10, 16, 23)
(1, 10, 17, 22)
(1, 10, 18, 21)
(1, 10, 19, 20)
(1, 11, 15, 23)
(1, 11, 16, 22)
(1, 11, 17, 21)
(1, 11, 18, 20)
(1, 12, 14, 23)
(1, 12, 15, 22)
(1, 12, 16, 21)
(1, 12, 17, 20)
(1, 12, 18, 19)
(1, 13, 14, 22)
(1, 13, 15, 21)
(1, 13, 16, 20)
(1, 13, 17, 19)
(1, 14, 15, 20)
(1, 14, 16, 19)
(1, 14, 17, 18)
(1, 15, 16, 18)
```

Is this the result you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, that's helpful.  I'm not sure if I've worded the question correctly, and I'm replying on my phone between jobs.  What I want is once I have ONE list of 4 numbers, lets take the first possible combination  (1,2,3,4) - I then want to apply the pairs check to make sure no pair (1,2 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 or 3,4) equal 25.  If at least one pair ==25, then we jump to the next combination of 4 numbers - the next here being (1,2,3,5) even though the first doesn't fail the pairs test.  If that makes sense ..

Comment: Ah, since you've got this far, I figured you'll find out the last bit too ;-) If I understand your problem correctly, you could use `if sum(pair) == 25: break` to quit the for-loop. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you.  That looks like what I want.  I won't be sure until I plug it in and evaluate it myself.  I think my biggest issue is I'm a novice programmer in all codes, and only really used to BASIC. What's getting me, I think, is the flow control.  In BASIC I would use ugly GOTO's to take the program back to where I wanted.  But that doesn't work in py.  I was trying to work out of I should be using all() or any() and/or break, return, or continue.  I was concerned that after evaluating the first pair in the loop, it woul go onto the next operation.

Comment: Ok, that appears to be perfect.  I've accepted this as the answer.  Thank you.  What is the point of print(repr(... ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. In this case `repr(...)` is not necessary, so you could also just use `print(four_numbers)` or something differently. I generally use `repr` for testing / debugging / demonstration purposes, since it provides a bit more information. Of course you can modify the code to fit your own purposes if you do not need to print the results. My example code merely demonstrates the principle and the answer to your question.